# Loading multiple files in HTML <head> in Grunt using globbing

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, gruntjs

Is there any kind of Grunt task or plugin for loading many files in the `<head>` of an HTML page using globbing?

We're using Ember.js and starting to see a lot of duplication:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/(controller).js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/(controller).js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/(controller).js">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/models/(model).js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/models/(model).js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/models/(model).js">
```

In our Gruntfile we use the globbing pattern that's pretty common in Grunt tasks, something like `scripts/{,*/}*.coffee`.

Is there any kind of plugin we can use to drop in a glob pattern into our HTML page to load all of these at once?

This would be pretty useful if we could use it to load CSS, as well. My guess is we'd need some kind of non-specific file loader where we can just specify a pattern and directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grunt-html-build` (https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) should do the job. You can define a HTML template with placeholders for scripts, styles and other HTML templates, which is then compiled by the plugin.

Grunt HTMLBuild config

```
htmlbuild: {
    dev: {
        src: 'index.html',
        dest: 'build/',
        options: {
            styles: {
                app: 'styles/*.css'
            },
            scripts: {
                app: 'scripts/*.js'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- build:style app -->
        <!-- /build -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- build:script app -->
        <!-- /build -->
    </body>
</html>
```

This compiles the HTML template from `index.html` into `build/index.html`, including all styles and scripts under `styles/` and `scripts/`.